# Switching language on ASP.NET app using master page

Tags: asp.net, localization, master-pages, cultureinfo

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.NET to build a web app. Most of my web pages are based on a single master page. This master page contains three button links that act as language switches; the `Click` event handlers look like this:

```
protected void lbuLangEN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SwitchLanguage(string.Empty);
}  

protected void lbuLangES_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SwitchLanguage("es");
}
```

Then I have my private method `SwitchLanguage`:

```
private void SwitchLanguage(string culture)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
}
```

As far as I understand, this should be enough to make the pages based on my master page exhibit a localised behaviour, i.e. get their resources from the appropriate local `resx` file according to culture. However, it is not working. They always appear in Spanish, which is my browser's default language. I have set some trace messages at the entry and exit points of `SwitchLanguage`, and apparently the current thread is not changing its culture info: every time `SwitchLanguage` is called, the current thread's culture is "es-ES", regardless of what my code has just set.

Is there any problem with my code or with the approach I am taking? Thanks.

Comment: The problem with that is you are only changing the language on the current Thread, and each request is its own thread.

Comment: @vcsjones: I see. So I would need to store the language setting and somehow set it for each request, right? Is there any commonly used technique for this?

Comment: you could do the trick by setting a cookie, transfer the request to the same path as in the request was, build a httpmodule and read out the cookie there and set the uiculture on the thread

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `OnAcquireRequestState` in `Global.asax` to change the culture.  It is called right after the session is loaded, but before any master page event.

So in the button event handler, you set a session variable to the desired current culture.  Then you redirect to the current page.  The `Global.asax` event can then pick up the new language, right before the masterpage loads:

```
protected void OnAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cultureName = "en-GB";
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null &&
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CultureName"] is string)
        cultureName = HttpContext.Current.Session["CultureName"];

    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == cultureName) 
        return;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this sounds like a good approach. Where do I wire up the OnAcquireRequestState event handler?

Comment: @CesarGon: Literally in the file called `Global.asax`.  It should already be there, otherwise you can copy it from a newly created ASP.NET web application.

Comment: @Andomar: It wasn't there (I'm using VS 2008), but I added it, plus a line in Application_Start like this: `this.AcquireRequestState += Application_OnAcquireRequestState;` Sounds good?

Comment: @Andomar: BTW, I get an exception thrown because, apparently, session state is not available inside `OnAcquireRequestState`, at least on one of the first few calls when the app is starting up. Any ideas how to go around this?

Comment: @CesarGon: Right, that sounds familiar, there are always requests for which there is no session.  To avoid the exception, use `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead of `Request.Session` (edited in answer)

Comment: @Andomar: Thanks. I found that HttpContext.Current.Session may be null on app startup as well, but I can simply perform a check for that and `return` if that's the case. Solved my problem, anyway. :-)

Answer (score 3):

For any body using @Andomar solution, the method should be named Application_AcquireRequestState positioned in Global.ascx code (e.g. below the Application_Start), and no event handlers are required to be attached. (If you do anything other than this you may encounter NullReferenceException even with no code in the method body! or your method will not run at all)
So the code will be something like this:

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cultureName = "en-GB";
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null &&
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CultureName"] is string)
        cultureName = HttpContext.Current.Session["CultureName"];

    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == cultureName) 
        return;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override the InitializeCulture method on page level to set the UICulture

Comment: I am working with master pages; `MasterPage` does not have an `InitializeCulture` method.

Comment: that's why I said, do it at page level, nevermind just give me a -1, jezus :) :)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't like to have the same code repeated in every page. I'm sure there's a solution that avoids that.

Comment: think a little bit harder on how you could avoid that and you have your solution :) btw watch out with setting the CurrentCulture also if you only need translations!

Comment: I'm with Tim; inherit from your own "Page" instead of System.Web.Page.